# Redirect url masking http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 url with same portal.
url-1 :- http://my.domain.com
url-2 :- http://client.domain.com
But i want to redirect client url http to https. And my url work with http.
How can redirect client url using .htaccess ?

Comment: You want to redirect HTTP client.domain.com to HTTPS my.domain.com?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Edit:

"Client domain to https"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to redirect client domain to https and our domain to http.